# Filtering the line with the largest value for a given ID

Tags: text-processing, command-line, numeric-data

I have a tabular file in which the first column has IDs and the second one has numeric values. I need to generate a file that contains only the line with the largest score for each ID.

So, I want to take this:

```
ES.001      2.33
ES.001      1.39
ES.001    119.55
ES.001     14.55
ES.073      0.35
ES.073     17.95
ES.140      1.14
ES.140     53.88
ES.140     18.28
ES.178    150.27
```

And generate this:

```
ES.001    119.55
ES.073     17.95
ES.140     53.88
ES.178    150.27
```

Is there a way of doing this from a bash command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of data, sorting may take a long time.
We can get the result without sorting (but using more memory) like this:

```
awk 'a[$1]<$2{a[$1]=$2}END{for(i in a){print(i,a[i])}}' infile
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `sort` to sort them by first field, and then by second field in numerically descending order.  Use Awk to print only the first line for each distinct first field value.

```
sort -k1,1 -k2rn inputfile | awk '!a[$1]++'
```